# Compilation error in Java 8 because equality constraints

Tags: java

I copied below piece of code from a class file and pasted to my Java code but my compiler throws below message.

```
"Required type:
Optional
<T>
Provided:
Optional
<Object>

no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Object conforms to T inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: T lower bounds: Object"
```

Only way to avoid this error is by Type Casting Optional to Optional.ofNullable(object) in getById method. I dont want to type cast it as am not sure of side effect.

```
    private static final InheritableThreadLocal<ThreadContext> THREAD_LOCAL = new NamedInheritableThreadLocal("DCL Thread Context") {
        protected ThreadContext initialValue() {
            return new ThreadContext();
        }

        protected ThreadContext childValue(ThreadContext parentValue) {
            return new ThreadContext(parentValue);
        }
    };

    private ThreadContext() {
        this.contextRegistry = new HashMap<>();
    }

    private ThreadContext(ThreadContext parent) {
        this.contextRegistry = new HashMap(parent.contextRegistry);
    }

    public static <T, V extends ThreadContextContributorId<T>> Optional<T> getById(@NonNull Class<V> contributorId) {
        ThreadContext threadContext = THREAD_LOCAL.get();
        Object object = threadContext.contextRegistry.get(contributorId);
        return  Optional.ofNullable(object);
    }
```

Is the a way to avoid this compilation error or is it ok to typecast it ?

Comment: Does `contextRegistry.get(contributorId)` return a `V`, a `T`, or is this type parameter actually irrelevant?

Comment: This question is not answerable without knowing what `threadContext.contextRegistry` is at the very least.

Comment: Look at the method `getById`. You are creating an `Object` there that you wrap in an `Optional`, so you're trying to return an `Optional<Object>`. But the return type of the method is `Object<T>`. So the cause of the error is clear: an `Optional<Object>` is not an `Optional<T>`, therefore you get an error. Make sure that you return a value of the correct type, or change the signature of the method to match the type of the return value.